# R Studio - Can I color the second row of a dataframe, and export it to excel with the color?

Tags: r

I know I can do this easily in Excel, but can I color the second row(or any row I want) in R Studio and write.xlsx write out to excel with that color on? I saw some posts online, but that would just print out a picture and I can't export to excel. I've included a reproducible example.

```
data <- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67, 71, 64, 65, 66, 68, 66, 
          71, 67, 68, 68, 56, 62, 60, 61, 63, 64, 63, 59)
grp <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:4], c(4,6,6,8)))
df <- data.frame(group=grp, dt=data)
```

Comment: You can't do it with base R. There are some packages yo can try: `openxlsx`, `XLConnect`

Comment: I will still need to manually color if I use XLConnect. I would have thousands of same data and I do not want to color them manually. It would be great if there are some lines of code to generalize it.

Comment: What do you mean by "manual"? You can definitely automate this process using `XLConnect`

Comment: Use package `openxlsx`. You'll use `createStyle()` and `addStyle()` many times.